# ERROR: PHP is not running

Tags: server, apache2, wordpress, php7

I installed [Wordpress](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/wordpress.html), php7.0 and apache2. I also installed the php7.0 module for apache and it is enabled.

I can create a php file (named phpinfo.php) with content `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and can see the correct output when I open `http://localhost/phpinfo.php`.

My problem is when I try to open `http://localhost/blog/wp-admin/install.php`, it says:

```
**ERROR: PHP is not running**
```

and **shows the whole installation page without the interpreted php**.

Does somebody know what the cause of that is, or even better, how I can fix it?

Comment: Make sure you have wordpress needed php modules installed in you apache server

Comment: ... `sudo apt install wordpress` should require these modules as dependencies. But you can try to install them as it is described under the section *Pre-Requirements* from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421).

Comment: Thank you  @pa4080 there were two dependencies that missed! Its working perfectly now. Will you write this as an 'answer'? I can then accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the @George's [suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953943/error-php-is-not-running?noredirect=1#comment1520708_953943) and @Moe's [report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/953943/error-php-is-not-running?noredirect=1#comment1520716_953943), actually, some PHP dependencies were missing. As it is described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421), all php dependencies for **Wordpress** can be installed through the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php-curl php-gd php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-xml php-xmlrpc
```

Answer (score 0):

This no longer works with Ubuntu 18.04.2 as mcrypt is deprecated.

For a fix, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031921/php-mcrypt-package-missing-in-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts).