# php-mcrypt package missing in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS

Tags: apt, server, package-management, apache2, php

Is the `php-mcrypt` package missing in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS?

```
apt install php-mcrypt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php-mcrypt is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php-mcrypt' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Ubuntu php-mcrypt : https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&keywords=php-mcrypt&searchon=names ... No php-mcrypt for 18.04 .

Answer (score 41):

Mcrypt has been deprecated in PHP 7.2, so it's not available by default.

You can still install the mcrypt extension using pecl. These instructions are for the `apache` web server.

```bash
# Install prerequisites
sudo apt-get install php-dev libmcrypt-dev gcc make autoconf libc-dev pkg-config

# Compile mcrypt extension
sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
# Just press enter when it asks about libmcrypt prefix

# Enable extension for apache
echo "extension=mcrypt.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

# Restart apache
sudo service apache2 restart
```

That should get you going.

In the long term you might want to replace `mcrypt`, it's deprecated for a reason.

Comment: Or make use of the `phpenmod` utlility:

`echo "extension=mcrypt.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mcrypt.ini`

`sudo phpenmod mcrypt`

Comment: Thanks @Epskampei

Comment: /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mcrypt.ini: No such file or directory

Answer (score 11):

I did the following to get this working...

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mcrypt
```

If you're running php5.6 or 7.0 then you can use the following

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-mcrypt
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mcrypt
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 has php7.2 in fact after added ppa repository and installet php7.1-mcrypt, when i do a2enmod mcrypt the response is "module mcrypt is not exists" !

Comment: you're likely using php 7.2 (`/etc/php/7.2`) -- this installs it to 7.1 (`/etc/php/7.1/`) and only works if you also install/use that version of php `apt-get install php7.1`

Answer (score 5):

First Check whether the mcrypt PHP module is present:

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
```

To install the mcrypt PHP module we first need to satisfy the following prerequisites:

```
sudo apt install php-dev libmcrypt-dev php-pear
```

Now we are ready to install mcrypt PHP module on our Ubuntu 18.04 system:

```
$ sudo pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
$ sudo pecl install mcrypt-1.0.1
```

Open the /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini file and insert:

```
extension=mcrypt.so
```

All done. When successful, checking for the presence of the mcrypt PHP module should produce the following output:

```
$ php -m | grep mcrypt
mcrypt
```

**References**

- [How to install mcrypt PHP module on Ubuntu 18.04 Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-mcrypt-php-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-linux): This answer drawn very heavily from this article.

Comment: Please be more scrupulous with referencing sources, I have added in the appropriate link. Please read here: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19789/57576

Answer (score 4):

php mcrypt has been removed in php 7.2 http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php