# How install mcrypt for PHP7.2

Tags: apache2, mysql, php, programming, phpmyadmin

I want to install a script on my locahost, i installed apache2, php7.2 and mysql

The problem that i have is running this command:

phpenmod mcrypt

it ALWAYS trow the same thing when i trow it in the console:

WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mcrypt ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available

PD: SOLUTION founded(see comentary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

After re-installing the entire SO, in a clean instalation i made this:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04

Then:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04

Then:

https://websiteforstudents.com/install-php-7-2-mcrypt-module-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

And lastly:

## Enable extension for apache

echo "extension=mcrypt.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini

and:

echo "extension=mcrypt.so" | sudo tee -a /etc/php/7.2/mods-available/mcrypt.ini

sudo phpenmod mcrypt

The three last steps are from:

[php-mcrypt package missing in Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031921/php-mcrypt-package-missing-in-ubuntu-server-18-04-lts)

I really thanks to Epskampie and Werner for the solution