# Can't access my apache server out of my local network(wordpress)

Tags: permissions, apache2, wordpress, websites

I just made a website through Apache server and word-press. I am able to access it when i am connected to local network.Although i have done port forwarding settings to my router and through ufw i can't access it  from other networks. I am using 'public_ip'/site1 (when i am from local 192.168.x.x) but i get 403 forbidden. If i don't use /site1 i got the page that says Apache works, and i suppose that means my port-forwarding works well. So i believe it has to do with word-press settings or /var/www/html/site1 permissions. Here is ls -l  /var/www/html/site1 output:
everything is -rwxr-xr-x except wp-admin,wp-content,wp-includes which is drwxr-xr-x
thanks in advance guys
edit: virtual host conf file is the apache default(000-default.conf)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please post the content of your virtual host configuration file.

Comment: i edit it, it is the defualt apache conf

Comment: Please review section **3.B. Setup Apache2: Append WordPress to an existing Virtual Host** in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/941947/566421. In addition for your case you do not need of the `Alias` directive, and maybe you should add `ServerName <your-LAN-ip>` and `ServerAlias <your-public-ip>` or vice versa. I would prefer to buy a cheap domain name, for example the price of *.me, .ninja, .space, .site* is about $4/year - you can buy it from www.domain.com or any other DNS provider.