# Wordpress doesn't open with localhost/blog

Tags: 18.04, server, apache2, wordpress

After running  I get:

```
apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: 
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-02-29 15:15:32 CET; 3min 49s ago
  Process: 22356 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCES
  Process: 22045 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/
  Process: 22362 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
 Main PID: 22366 (apache2)
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 4578)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─22366 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22367 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22368 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22369 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22370 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22371 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─22376 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Feb 29 15:15:32 alexander-Latitude-E6500 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Se
Feb 29 15:15:32 alexander-Latitude-E6500 apachectl[22362]: AH00558: apache2: Cou
Feb 29 15:15:32 alexander-Latitude-E6500 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Ser
```

What can I do?

Comment: You need to provide more information, for us to help you.

How did you install Wordpress?

Where is this output coming from?

What is the exact problem you are encountering?

Comment: I followed the tutorial 'Install and configure WordPress'. at nr 5. Configure WordPress it said to open localhost/blog in your browser. But nothing happened and the message showed: 'Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80' . Output in my previous question was after 'systemctl status apache2'. I did restart Mysql before that

Comment: I found one mistake already. The file '/etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php' was empty so I copied the proposed text into it. Made sure I saved it.

Comment: Are you sure you also did step 3? 
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-wordpress#3-configure-apache-for-wordpress

Comment: I did checked step 3 done step '4. Configure database' and restarted the service mysql. And that was it.     Thank you Søren to make me to double check every step.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WordPress Installation Failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/941928/wordpress-installation-failed)